# Automatically uncheck Boolean field depending on current year

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, expression, qgis-custom-widgets

I'm preparing QGIS for field work. We want to check on street lamp posts. I have three columns:

1. "Checked" (type Boolean)
2. "last checked" (type string, contains only the year of the last check)
3. "next check" (type string, contains only the year of the next check)

My goal is, when a field worker ticks the checkbox (column 1) it automatically fills out the other two columns ("last checked" with the default expression: `Case When "checked" is TRUE Then year(now()) END` and "next check" with: `...year(now())+6 ...` as they need to be revisited 6 years later.

This works ok with one restrain: As soon the year arrives, where a new visit of the lamp post is needed, the checkbox should be automatically unchecked - map/layout wise I solved that with an virtual column that checks if the checkbox is ticked AND if the year is same or smaller than the current year. But I need this also in the data, not only in the map layout. Is there a possibility to uncheck all lamp posts as soon 2021 arrives? Like a yearly cron-job, more or less.

Answer (score 1):

Would it work if you would make also the *Checked* column to work with a default value, with something like this:

```sql
CASE 
   WHEN "next check" < year(now()) THEN FALSE
   ELSE "Checked"
END
```

Comment: but then every post has to be manuelly edited, so the default value is applied or am i wrong?